# Content flows over scrollbar

Tags: css, overflow, css-position, parallax

weird bug here. Searched on the internet for hours but no working solutions yet :(

https://www.*****.*****/

It only happens on the page with parallax, a page without parallax is fine (biografie page).

What happens is that when you look closely, you will see that the white transparant-ish header flows OVER your scrollbar.

When taking a closer look you will see that the whole body is floating over my scrollbar.

Does anyone know a way to 100% fix this? I tried lots and lots of answers on the internet but none gave me a working solution.

Hope someone can explain to me what is happening and how to solve it.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't place the menu below the scrollbar, because the scrollbar on pages with `.parallax` containers is not the `<body>`'s scrollbar, but `.parallax`'s scrollbar.
And you can't place element A between element B and element B's scrollbar, unless element A is a descendant of element B.

However, the real problem is not placing the menu under the scrollbar. The real problem is being able to use the scrollbar (click its top arrow) ***through*** the menu, where they overlap.

Which is quite possible, using:

```
.menu {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.menu-wrapper > * {
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

(This makes the menu transparent to pointer events, except for children of `.menu-wrapper`, which do not overlap the scrollbar).

Comment: You are the man! this works perfectly indeed! thank you so much! was trying to figure this out (never seen it before) all night but never got to a solution. You just made my day!

Comment: I have one more question though... is there any way to properly fix all of this? on a PC everything is fine but when I try to scroll on a tablet or mobile phone (both Apple in this example) the scrolling is all messed up. It does scroll but as soon as you take your finger off the screen it stops scrolling instead of the normal scrolling (which gradually stops by itself).

Best regards

Comment: @Amgelo, that's a completely separate question. The principle of SO requires you to ask it separately, so anyone with a similar problem could benefit from the answer. In particular, it's because the parallax method you're using is flawed. There are very many parallax methods and only a handful are iOS friendly. In short, you got the wrong theme. My guess is not even its creators know about it (or they would have chosen a better parallax technique).

Comment: My apologies, I will think about this in the future :) and thank you for your answer!